# Choosing the collection when creating a user

Tags: meteor, meteor-accounts

Is there anyway that I can chose what collection the Accounts.createUser function inserts to? I am not wanting a user to be created into the user collection as I am already using that collection for users using my app and am wanting to distinguish the two users.

Comment: I'm curious why you want to do this? Wouldn't it be easier to add a flag to their record so that they are treated differently to other users?

Comment: afaik there is no way of doing this without forking the Accounts package and changing the collection name there. It's not a preference or setting.

Comment: Ah okay, I was just wanting to distinguish them as I do not want someone who has logged in through the app to be able to login to the website and vice versa. I'm assuming there is no way to add settings to the meteor.loginWithPassword function either.

Comment: This is the XY Problem, you really don't want to put users at different places, just add a prop to them something like `userType` or anything

Comment: Also if you don't want mobile app user to login on the web-app put a callback on the server side and return only if a certain prop is what you want.